# Why is Doom Emacs GUI not accepting keyboard input?

Tags: osx, doom

Noob question. I downloaded Doom Emacs following the installation instructions in the documentation. Now when I run the `emacs` command, it opens up the Doom Emacs window. Unfortunately, as I try interacting with the program with my keyboard, it continues typing in the terminal window. I can click around the application using my cursor, but am unable to use my keyboard.

I'm not running as the daemon or have it aliased in any other way.

Comment: Do you have the same issue when you run a vanilla Emacs with no configuration, using the `emacs -q` command ?

Comment: Yes, it does the same thing. No input from the keyboard is working, just the cursor (which isn't very helpful).

Comment: You have the command ```doom doctor``` to check out your installation. Try it. A second question: since doom uses evil mode, did you pressed first ```i``` or ```a``` to insert some characters?

Comment: Are you using emacs-mac? If so I had the same problem and I resolved it by uninstalling emacs-mac and installing emacs-plus instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with emacs-mac both with and without the Doom Emacs cofig, but I don't think the `emacs` executable is supposed to work in this way.

This page has some examples of starter scripts: https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport/blob/master/docs/emacs-start-helpers.md

The following script worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec $(brew --prefix)/opt/emacs-mac/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs.sh "$@"
```

Installing emacs-mac with `brew install emacs-mac --with-starter` will create this script automatically instead of the `emacs` symlink. Then starting Emacs with `emacs` works without the input issues.